# crash when i try to get id "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near"

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, fragment, logcat

hello im very new to android programming and have been stumped for hours on an error. What is supposed to happen is, after it loads up all of the quotes from my table if I click on one my it should pass the id, to a new fragment and load it up again on a fragment. But what ends up happening is when I click the quote, I get an error and it points to my getItemID method in my DatabaseHelper class. The error I get is I keep getting is -

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECTIDFROMQuote_TableWHEREQuote": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECTIDFROMQuote_TableWHEREQuote = 'Play it, Sam. Play 'As Time Goes By.'
```

then get pointed to - getItemID(DatabaseHelper.java:78)

any help would help thanks so much.

(this is the activity that holds the listFragments and favoriteFragment)

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class FavoriteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


final String LOG_TAG = FavoriteActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorite);


    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "youre now in FavoriteActivity ");


    FavoriteListFragment newFragment = new FavoriteListFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.favorite_Container, newFragment);
    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();


}

}
```

(this is the fragment that loads after you click on the listview quote)
(This is where im having issues in the ID)

```
public class FavoriteFragment extends Fragment {

DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
private String selectedQuote;
private int selectedID;
private TextView savedQuoteView;
final String LOG_TAG = FavoriteFragment.class.getSimpleName();

public FavoriteFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "youre now in FavoriteFragment ");

    Bundle openBundle = getArguments();
    selectedID = openBundle.getInt("ID", -1);
    String selectedQuote = openBundle.getString("quote", "empty");
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorite, container, false);
    Button deleteBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);

    deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Log.e(LOG_TAG, "selectedID : " + selectedID + " selectedQuote : " + selectedQuote);
            mDatabaseHelper.deleteQuote(selectedID, selectedQuote);
            savedQuoteView.setText("");
            FavoriteListFragment favoriteListFragment = new FavoriteListFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.favorite_Container, favoriteListFragment);
            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "removed from database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    savedQuoteView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.savedQuote);
    savedQuoteView.setText(selectedQuote);

    return view;
}}
```

(this is the listFragment that shows my table)

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class FavoriteListFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "FavoriteListFragment";
private ListView listView;
DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;

public FavoriteListFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // final String LOG_TAG = FavoriteActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorite_list, container, false);
    listView = view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    //Log.e(LOG_TAG, "mDataBaseHelper: " + mDatabaseHelper);
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "you're now in FavoriteListFragment ");
    // Log.e(LOG_TAG, "this is your list view " + listView);
    populateListView();
    return view;
}

private void populateListView() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "youre in populateListView");

    //get the data and append to a list
    Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getAllQuotes();
    ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    while (data.moveToNext()) {
        //get the value from the database in column 1
        //then add it to the ArrayList
        listData.add(data.getString(1));
    }


    //create the list adapter and set the adapter
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //set an onItemClickListener to the ListView
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            String quote = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

            Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getItemID(quote); //get the id associated with that name
            int itemID = -1;
            while (data.moveToNext()) {
                itemID = data.getInt(0);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on " + quote);
            }
            if (itemID > -1) {

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onItemClick: The ID is: " + itemID);
                FavoriteFragment newFragment = new FavoriteFragment();

                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt("ID", itemID);
                args.putString("quote", quote);
                newFragment.setArguments(args);

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.favorite_Container, newFragment);
                transaction.commit();

            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No ID associated with that name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

(This is the handler i am using)

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "DatabaseHelper";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Quote_Table";
private static final String COL0 = "ID";
private static final String COL1 = "Quote";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COL1 + " TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int v1, int v2) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean addData(String item) {
    SQLiteDatabase dataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COL1, item);

    long result = dataBase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns all the data from database
 */
public Cursor getAllQuotes() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;
}

/**
 * Returns only the ID that matches the name passed in
 */

public Cursor getItemID(String quote) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT " + COL0 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
            " WHERE " + COL1 + " = '" + quote + "'";
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;
}

/**
 * Delete from database
 *
 * @param id
 * @param quote
 */
public void deleteQuote(int id, String quote) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
            + COL0 + " = '" + id + "'" + " AND " + COL1 + " = '" + quote + "'";
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "deleteName: query: " + query);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "deleteName: Deleting " + quote + " from database.");
    db.execSQL(query);
}

}
```

(in case you wanted to see the logcat said):

```
  randomquote.hfad.com.randomquote.DatabaseHelper.getItemID(DatabaseHelper.java:71)
     at 

 randomquote.hfad.com.randomquote.FavoriteListFragment$1.onItemClick(FavoriteListFragment.java:72)
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that quote contains characters that aren't being escaped correctly (quotes at a guess). I'd suggest trying to use the query convenience method which does escaping for you.

As such try using the following :-

```
public Cursor getItemID(String quote) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String[] columns = new String[]{COL0};
    String whereclause = COL1+"=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{quote};

    return db.query(TABLE_NAME,columns,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);

}
```

- Note this is in-principle code and has not been tested, so it may contain errors.